# Interrupt waiting read threads by ReentrantReadWriteLock

Tags: java, concurrency, resources

I have a list of resources. Reader processes can access each of these concurrently but sometimes a write process comes and alters the object which requires that no read process is running on the resource while updating. Java's [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) seems to handle this situation correctly so i've assigned one of these to each resource to maximalize throughput of the application. However i'm facing a problem with entry removal. Some write processes may delete accessible resources from this list.

Imagine the following scennario:

- Delete process acquires a lock on the resource being deleted
- Meanwhile reader process(es) reach the `readLock().lock()` statement and starts to wait in the queue for the writelock to be released
- Delete process removes the resource from the list and calls shutdown on the resource to finalize
- Delete process releases the write lock on the resource
- The first waiting read process is resumed and starts working with the now inconsistent resource object

How can i correctly handle this situation? It would be good if i could call `interrupt()` on the waiting read threads however as the API description of [`getQueuedReaderThreads`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html#getQueuedReaderThreads%28%29) states it's not reliable because new threads can acquire the read lock while the list is built so i can't be sure that i'll cancel all threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be much easier to associate a "deleted" flag with each resource.

When reader acquires the lock, it should check that flag and correctly handle the situation when resource was deleted. Since writer releases its lock immediately after deleting the resource, and each reader should release its lock immediately after it found out that resource was deleted there should be no long blocking here, therefore you don't need to interrupt threads.

You can hide this behaviour behind your own API (for example, you can throw something like `ResourceDeletedException` when reader acquires a lock on deleted resource).

Comment: This actually makes sense. I can extend my instance object with my own read lock and unlock mechanism and this can check the shutdown flag just after acquiring the read lock and throw the exception. I'll give it a try.